# Impulse response ltspice

Tags: voltage, ltspice, pulse

Is any one able to explain why I am not getting an impulse response when I probe across L1? The voltage shown seems to be the same no matter where I probe on the circuit.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtain an approximation for the impulse response of the circuit using a time-domain simulation in LTSpice](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/692810/obtain-an-approximation-for-the-impulse-response-of-the-circuit-using-a-time-dom)

Comment: no :/ it doesn’t

Comment: it just seems to be the exact same schematic, and nothing changed since you asked that question?

Comment: yes but i deleted the last one as it wasn’t specific enough

Comment: Don't do that. Edit the original question instead.

Comment: ah, I see sorry, I will next time

Comment: @Pizaaaa have you tried calculating the (3dB, half power) *bandwidth* of your R-L on paper? It's not hard, and I'm sure you've learned to do that before you were given LTspice, you might just need to remember how to do that. Then, compare that with the bandwidth of the pulse you're giving.

Comment: (I would honestly have expected you to have done that before asking about it, it just seems something that is very natural to do when a simulation of something simple is not what you expect it to be)

Comment: this is a homework question i was given, we were asked to calculate the impulse response of the circuit prior and now use ltspice to confirm it. we were given this exact circuit, my problem is more with using ltspice itself rather than the calculations.

Comment: A unit impulse has a volt-time area of unity. You should also not use node numbers but instead use labels that are clearly marked on your schematic. And, if node 2 is the output node then, the displayed waveform will (in your circuit) be exactly the same as the input voltage (not an impulse). Just think about how an inductor behaves under these circumstances.

Comment: thank you so much! I thought it was not possible to make an actual Dirac delta function  hence why I used the values above, where it is not quite unity but often sufficient to approximate an impulse for the purpose of simulating the impulse response. Also I added a label for Vo between the resistor and the inductor, is this what you meant?

Comment: @Pizaaaa A little more emphatic than winny's "don't do that": deleting and reposting a question is explicitly *not allowed*.

Comment: so sorry, thank you for letting me know, i’ll make sure to go through the rules again before submitting

Comment: so, show your calculations. How are we supposed to help you with the calculations if you don't show them, don't ask about them?

Comment: i didn’t need help with the calculations? the question has been solved below I needed help with simulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you are not checking the UIC in the .TRAN card. Let's do that:

[image]

We know that \$\tau=\frac{L}{R}=100\:\mu\text{s}\$. So we'd expect that within \$5\tau\$ the output should settle-out. And that's exactly what we see in the curve above (highlighted with a blue circle.)

What happens when you don't check the UIC is that LTspice goes through an *"initial transient solution"* step (sometimes shortened to **"ITS"**), which takes place immediately prior to t=0. This means that it works out the DC settling point first before running the simulation. You don't want that. The UIC option on the .TRAN card tells Spice to avoid this initial **ITS** step. That's what you want.

Comment: Shouldn't the impulse have a height of `1t` so the integral equals 1?  Isn't that the definition of an impulse, or am I remembering stuff wrong again?

Comment: @SteKulov That's a step. It's called PULSE there, but there's no period given so it just rises with a 1 ps rise time from 0 to 1 and stays there.

Comment: Ahhhh.  Gotcha.  I didn't realize your PULSE definition doesn't match the one in the question.  My mistake.

Comment: @SteKulov Yeah. I think the questioner was using "impulse response" loosely. We tend to read too much into the words used, since between specialists that what one should do. Instead, I looked at the presentation and graph, which essentially showed me a numerical simulation detail in how LTspice runs and starts up and handles the ITS step. From there, I next looked at the PULSE statement used. And ***that*** is what told me the questioner wanted to apply a *step* and not an *impulse* and was wondering why the output didn't look as they expected. So I answered ***that*** question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure if your interested in the theoretical value. But we can obtain a general function for the output voltage using the convolution property of the Laplace transform:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{V}_\text{o}\left(t\right)&=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{sL}}{\displaystyle\text{sL}+\text{R}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle\text{sL}}{\displaystyle\text{sL}+\text{R}}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{L}\delta\left(t-\tau\right)-\text{R}\exp\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}\left(\tau-t\right)}{\displaystyle\text{L}}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{L}}\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\delta\left(t-\tau\right)\space\text{d}\tau-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle\text{L}}\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\exp\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}\left(\tau-t\right)}{\displaystyle\text{L}}\right)\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\text{V}_\text{i}\left(t\right)\left(2\theta\left(t\right)-1\right)-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle\text{L}}\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\exp\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}\left(\tau-t\right)}{\displaystyle\text{L}}\right)\space\text{d}\tau
\end{alignat*}
\tag1
$$